# PostgreSQL 9.3:Updating table(order column) from another table, getting same values in rows

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I need help with updating table from another table in Postgres Db.

Long story short we ended up with corrupted data in db, and now I need to update one table with values from another.

I have table with this data `table wfc`:

```
| step_id | command_id | commands_order |
|---------|------------|----------------|
|       1 |          1 |              0 |
|       1 |          2 |              1 |
|       1 |          3 |              2 |
|       1 |          4 |              3 |
|       1 |          1 |              0 |
|       2 |          2 |              0 |
|       2 |          3 |              1 |
|       2 |          3 |              1 |
|       2 |          4 |              3 |
```

and I want to update values in command_order column from another table, so I can have result like this:

```
| step_id | command_id | commands_order|
|---------|------------|---------------|
|       1 |          1 |             0 |
|       1 |          2 |             1 |
|       1 |          3 |             2 |
|       1 |          4 |             3 |
|       1 |          1 |             4 |
|       2 |          2 |             0 |
|       2 |          3 |             1 |
|       2 |          3 |             2 |
|       2 |          4 |             3 |
```

It was looking like easy task, but problem is to update rows for same `command_id`, it is writing same value in `commands_order`

**SQL that I tried is:**

```
UPDATE wfc 
SET commands_order = CAST(sq.input_step_id as INTEGER) 
FROM  ( 
SELECT wfp.step_id, wfp.input_command_id, wfp.input_step_id
from wfp 
order by wfp.step_id, wfp.input_step_id

   ) AS sq
WHERE  (wfc.step_id=sq.step_id AND wfc.command_id=CAST(sq.input_command_id as INTEGER));
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4efff4/4

I am pretty stuck with this, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't have option to edit question, just to add that table wfc doesn't have primary key.
I am aware of ctid that might be helpfull, but not sure how to use it in update

Comment: Yes, if you are updating based on combination of step_id and command_id and two rows have identical values in those fields, they will be updated with the same command_order.  If there is no unique identifier for the row, there will be now way to differentiate between them.

Comment: @JuliaLeder I am updating from another table, but yes, problem is same combination of step_id and command_id. So is it possible to update with different value in command_order? How ctid can help here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to number the rows in the order in which they were created, and as long as you understand that ctid will chnage on update and with VACCUUM FULL, you can do the following:

```
select step_id, command_id, rank - 1 as command_order 
from (select step_id, command_id, ctid as wfc_ctid, rank() over
         (partition by step_id order by ctid)
      from wfc) as wfc_ordered;
```

This will give you the wfc table with the ordering that you want.  If you do update the original table, the ctids will change, so it's probably safer to create a copy of the table with the above query.

Comment: Numbering rows in order they were created is not good for me. I need to update from another table (wfp). Any idea how can I achive this? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are not updating based on ctid, and only looking at step_id and command_id then you will get identical command_order, because there is absolutely no way to differentiate between rows which have identical values.  For example, you have two rows with step_id = 1 and command_id = 1. Based on what would you decide that one row would have command_order or 0 and another command_order of 4? You are either missing some information or trying to do the impossible.